# Accessing files from external SD card memory

Tags: android

I am very new to Android ecosystem.  Can I make a definitive conclusion that any stored files in an external SD memory can be read by any apps?

Caution Although the directories provided by getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs() are not accessible by the MediaStore content provider, other apps with the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission can access all files on the external storage, including these. If you need to completely restrict access for your files, you should instead write your files to the internal storage.  (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: external SD would be formatted FAT16/FAT32, which has absolutely no capacity for permissions. e.g. yes, any one can read/write anything they want on the external cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, BUT there is an important piece of information you need to know if you are deploying the app on KitKat OS and above. You cannot no longer write at any location in the SD card/internal storage as it was done before. The public directories can still be written in(Downloads, Pictures, Videos, etc), but that's it. You can write to private storage for your app and your app can only read from it, BUT you won't be able to view that location or the file if you were browsing the contents of the sdCard. The only exception is if your phone was rooted.

http://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-sdcard-changes

Example of writing to app private storage:

```
//Write to internal app storage
            FileOutputStream internalStorage = null;

        try
        {
            internalStorage = openFileOutput("capturedImage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedOutputStream buffer_output = new BufferedOutputStream(internalStorage);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, buffer_output);
        try
        {
            buffer_output.flush();
            buffer_output.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I am a little confused about this: "You cannot no longer write at any location in the SD card/internal storage as it was done before.".  With the SD card, did you imply an exteranl SD card?

Comment: So, with KitKat OS and above, can any apps be able to read any files on an external SD card?

Comment: From this excerpt: 
"Saving files that are app-private

If you are handling files that are not intended for other apps to use (such as graphic textures or sound effects used by only your app), you should use a private storage directory on the external storage by calling getExternalFilesDir(). "

It seemed to contradict my other excerption.

Comment: Sorry, I'l try to be a little more clear. Yes, an external SD card is what I was referring to. 

In terms of reading from files ALREADY on the external SD card, any app should be able to read those files as long as they have the read permission in their Android manifest xml file(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

I did not mean to confuse you by mentioning private storage and Kit-Kat. It was just me giving more information if you decided to start writing to the external storage in the future.