# App can't access external SD card (read-only)

Tags: java, android, permissions

I want my app to be able to read and copy files from the DCIM/MEDIA100 folder on an external SD card, but despite including the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in my AndroidManifest my app does not have visibility of the external SD card. I'm running Android 4.4.2

So when I execute the code below, m_subdirs will list "sdcard" (in internal storage), but not extSdCard (the external SD card). Am I completely unable to get read access to the external SD card in this Android release? I got the impresssion from the link below that reading from the external SD would be possible if I included the permissions above.
???
[Accessing files from external SD card memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042934/accessing-files-from-external-sd-card-memory)

```
m_dir = "/mnt";
m_subdirs = getDirectories(m_dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

kitkat 4.4.x has SD-card Restrictions .[see this page](http://www.xperiablog.net/2014/03/20/before-upgrading-to-kitkat-be-wary-of-sd-card-restrictions/)

Comment: Yes I was aware of those restrictions for WRITING to external cards, but was under the impression that READING from external SD cards should still be possible. Is that not the case?

Comment: @IanM: No, on 4.4+, [you have no arbitrary access to removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look under `/storage` and there you should find `sdcard1` or use [getExternalFilesDirs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: What I don't understand is why Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String.valueOf(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)) will take me to a location on the "internal" (emulated) SD card, when on the HTC One for example the photos app will store photos on the external ("physical") SD card. Shouldn't the camera app be using the standard API when writing files? (and shouldn't a developer be able to use the same API to access files created by the camera app?

Comment: "external", "internal" storage behavior changed considerably between Android 2.x, 4.x and 5.x again. This is explained in detail by  @CommonsWare link in his comment.

Comment: Thanks - I've read the article, which is extremely helpful. It does say that "apps can read files on removable media using the various undocumented and unsupported tricks for finding removable media". I guess I'm looking for a way of doing that (preferably based on the preferred API), since the "tricks" that I've tried so far have not succeeded in providing access to the folder that the default photo app uses for its storage. As I only want read-only access, I don't see that the changes from Android 4.4 onwards should preclude this. Or have I misinterpreted this?

Comment: Well on my device I can access `/storage/sdcard1/DCIM` without any problems for reading from a third party app.

Comment: ...specifically, the camera app stores files on secondary external storage, but I can't find a way in the API of accessing the folder that it uses for storage (e.g. /mnt/extSdCard/DCIM/100Media)

Comment: My last comment crossed with yours....what method do you use to access /storage/sdcard1/DCIM - do you hardcode this path?

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggested (as long as there is no better standard way).

Comment: Ok the issue for me is that this path is not the same on all devices (e.g. on the Samsung S4 it's /storage/extSdCard/DCIM). I was looking for a way of allowing the user to select their camera folder, by browsing to the root of /storage and asking them to choose the relevant sub-folder. This is because they have the option of configuring the camera app to save to either primary or secondary external storage (either the "internal sdcard" or the external sdcard).

Comment: ..but when I browse to /storage I only see the "internal" SD card, not the external one